# Notice: Undefined variable: after_widget in ....wp-content/plugins/wps-pro-login/includes/class-wps-pro-login-widget.php on line 200

Tags: php, wordpress

I get this notice on my site and I know it is probably some simple fix..

Notice: Undefined variable: after_widget in ....wp-content/plugins/wps-pro-login/includes/class-wps-pro-login-widget.php on line 200

here is the code starting on line 199:

```
        //echo $args['after_widget'];
            echo $after_widget;

}

// Update the widget settings.
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance['title'] = strip_tags( stripslashes($new_instance['title']) );
    $instance['avtar_size'] =  strip_tags( stripslashes($new_instance['avtar_size']) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to work with variable which doesn't exist. Use `isset` to check it.

```
if (isset($after_widget)) {
    echo $after_widget;
}
```

OR

```
echo isset($after_widget) ? $after_widget : '';
```

Comment: I used the second one and it worked, Thanks for the info